# What data can I safely remove, AKA, put a big partition in a smaller space

Tags: partitioning, ssd, uefi, migration

I have a system containing the following disks:

- 1x [Western Digital Caviar Black](https://www.wdc.com/products/internal-storage/wd-black-desktop.html) 1TB with Windows 10
- 1x Western Digital Caviar Black 1TB with Gentoo Linux
- 1x Western Digital Caviar Black 1TB with FreeBSD

In an effort to keep up with the times, I bought an extra [Hard Drive Cage with Trays](https://ttstoreusa.com/product/hard-drive-cage-with-hard-drive-trays-for-suppressor-f31-case/), an [ICY dock EZ-FIT Trio MB610SP Triple 2.5” SSD / HDD Bracket for Internal 3.5” Drive Bay](https://www.icydock.com/goods.php?id=240), and 3 [WD Blue 3D NAND SATA SSD x 250 GB](https://www.wdc.com/products/internal-ssd/wd-blue-3d-nand-sata-ssd.html).

I don't want this to become an advertisement for those products, but I linked them so readers can understand what I'm doing:

### Steps Done So Far

1. Insert the 3 Drives into the Tooless Drive Bracket.
2. Insert the Full Drive Bracket into the Drive Cage.

### Steps Not Done

1. Insert the new Drive Cage into my case, above the existing drive cage.
2. Connect the SATA cables and the power cables.
3. Move copies of existing OS'es to the new smaller drives, and keep the data separate on the original larger disks.

---

I checked with my OEM, [Xidax](https://www.xidax.com/), and double checked my [motherboard manual/support](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z270-A-PRO.html) to make sure I have six SATA ports, so in theory, or my opinion if you want to see it that way, it should take less space to run the OS, and faster, while leaving the 1TB drives to store things like Steam Games, the non-essential non-booting linux directories like `/usr`, `/home` etc, and the same for FreeBSD.  All I need to do is modify my `fstab` file in linux.

**Note**: This is currently all boot managed with [Roderick Smith's great tool for UEFI based systems Refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

Step 3 in the above steps, is where I'm stuck in my research.  All the research I've read and googled assumes that the target drive is greater than or equal to the source drive.  In my case the target is smaller than the source.  I realize that in order for me to shrink a 1TB NTFS partition, to 250 GB or less is a tall order.  With that in mind, a few questions come up, and I'm asking for your help:

1. Is it possible to point the Windows Registry to another location for the `Users`, and `Program Files` directories?  There may be more, but those are the ones that come to mind.
2. See #1: Will Windows itself explode metaphorically if the OS footprint exists on C:\Windows, while all the directories in #1 exist elsewhere?
3. Anyone with Refind or other boot managers, is it possible to have 2 identical versions of Windows on separate drives, using the same EFI partition?
4. If #3 isn't possible, am I allowed multiple EFI partitions with identical Windows bootloaders?  I know, I'm allowed multiple EFI partitions, but every time I've done it, they've all contained different EFI stubs for different OS'es.
5. Are any of the above approaches more viable than trying to delete what I don't need and shrink the partition?

Comment: 1: AFAIK the registry isn't *that* big, I don't see why you'd wanna move it off the SSD. 3: Not sure about Refind but with Grub it'd work.

Comment: @confetti don't want to move the registry, I want to point the registry on the SSD to the Directories on my original drive.  In short, I want a new Windows install on SSD pointing to installed programs on an old installation.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misread that part. Can't really comment on that as I don't use Windows but if you manage to get it done I don't see why it shouldn't work. But unless a migration tool for this exists I feel like you might be better and faster off by re-installing the software on the new SSD.